# Highchart columnrange, color code lines based on data

Tags: highcharts

is it possible to color code bars in highchart columnrange using the "GROUP" array in the json sample data shown below? So if its "IT" it would be say green, "Sierra" red. Any help would be immensely appreciated.Thanks.

```
{
    "name": "PW (md.h24mi)",
        "data": [
        [320, 320.06],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [320, 320.04]
    ],
        "PW": [
        ["PW0000025090"],
        ["PW0000025158"],
        ["PW0000025160"],
        ["PW0000025171"],
        ["PW0000025172"],
        ["PW0000025161"],
        ["PW0000025173"],
        ["PW0000025159"],
        ["PW0000025164"],
        ["PW0000025170"],
        ["PW0000024827"],
        ["PW0000024461"]
    ],
        "GROUP": [
        ["IT"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["IP"]
    ],
        "worksum": [
        ["Call Back Assist (CBA) Modification"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["Upgrade Consumer Wimax Firewall Modules to R77.10"]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforutnately it is not possible, but you can try to set color by [parameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.color)

Comment: Thank you. A bit disappointed but i appreciate your honesty -_-

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to combine these things all into the main data array...

for example:

```
{
  "name": "PW (md.h24mi)",
  "data": [
     { low:320   , high:320.06, PW:"PW0000025090", GROUP:"IT",           color:'green' },
     { low:319.05, high:319.1,  PW:"PW0000025158", GROUP:"Sierra",       color:'red'   },
     { low:319.05, high:319.1,  PW:"PW0000025160", GROUP:"RF Engineers", color:'blue'  }
  ]
}
```

You can then retrieve any/all of those values in the tooltip or label formatters to display on the chart, or use to determine other properties.

{{edit - updated to reflect the data format for the columnrange series type.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/tAc6Z/

Comment: I tried this in jsfiddle but it didnt work. Would it be possible to reproduce this in jsfiddle as an example please? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about it being a column range, and took the pairs in your data as [x,y] pairs.  That should instead have been low, high, in my code.  Answer updated, and fiddle included.